# Can I put one d3 layout on top of another one?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's the sort of thing I'm looking for.  Suppose I have two d3 layouts - for the sake of this question, let's say one of them is a map attached to some data and the other one is a pie chart which takes a list of numbers as input.  Assume that I can get both of them to run correctly on their own.

What I would like to do is create a document which displays the map layout and, when the user clicks on the map (or some other event), it sends some data to the pie chart layout and displays the pie chart in the upper-right hand corner of the map.  What is the easiest way to do this sort of thing?

Don't feel bound to the details of my example; the key thing is having one layout which triggers another layout in response to an event (and the second layout should be able to accept data which depends on the event).

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement your charts in the way it described in this article http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/. You will build two charts by using those two layouts internally. Your charts will probably be called map and pie. Once you implemented your charts, they tested and work as expected, you add extra logic. You assign a callback to the event ( ex. mouseclick ), which when clicked collects all the data from your map chart, appends a div element to where you need it to be and renders your pie chart in it.

This is how I would do that. Good luck!

Comment: This helped a lot - thanks!  For future googlers, I also had to read this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp to get control of positioning.